# Changing the coordinate system in P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

As you know P5 coordinate system doesn't start from the middle of the canvas plus the y axis is flipped 
My question is how to change the coordinates of p5 so it became the same as the Cartesian coordinate system

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`translate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate) to translate the origin to the center. Use [`scale`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) to flip the y axis:

```js
function draw() {
    translate(width/2, height/2); 
    scale(1, -1);

    // [...] 
}
```

Note, [`width`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/width) and [`height`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/height) is the width and height of the canvas.
`translate(width/2, height/2)` moves everything by the half width and height. It moves the objects of the scene from the top left to the center of the canvas.

---

This approach will cause that text to be flipped. To "unflip" the text again, each text must be inserted in a [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)/[`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop) block that reverses the flip::

```js
push();
scale(1, -1); // reverse the global flip
text(...);
pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to translating the *origin* and flipping the *y* axis, I came to this question looking to scale for "world coordinates" (coordinates that are *for the scene*, independent of the pixel dimensions of the canvas).

A few refinements I'd like to add to address my specific needs:

1. Set up some word coordinate variables:

   ```js
   let worldWidth = 640
   let worldHeight = 400
   let worldAspect = (worldHeight/worldWidth);
   ```
2. In `setup()` adjust the canvas to the width of the window, but maintain the world aspect ratio:

   ```js
   function setup() {
     createCanvas(windowWidth, windowWidth * worldAspect);
   }
   ```
3. Begin `draw()` by translating *origin* to the bottom left. To use world coordinates, one can scale by the canvas `height` and `width`, divided by world coordinates (remembering to also flip vertically by using negative `height`):

   ```js
   function draw() {
     translate(0, height);
     scale(width / worldWidth, -height / worldHeight);

     # ...
   }
   ```
4. For un-flipping text, if you need to do this often, write a function which wraps [text()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/text) to temporarily un-flip:

   ```js
   function wText(message, x, y, size) {
     push();
     scale(1, -1);
     textSize(size);
     text(message, x, -y);
     pop();
   }
   ```

   This maintains the world-coordinates scaling because successive calls to [scale()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/scale) are *cumulative*. It's also why we want to scale by one.
5. Now we can think in world coordinates, with *origin* in the bottom left and vertical *y* axis going *up*. For instance, this will always draw "hi" the right way up, in the top-right corner, and a medium sized true circle in the center, no matter the size of the window and canvas:

   ```js
   wText("hi", 580, 350, 50);
   circle(320, 200, 80);
   ```

   Note the use of world coordinates means we no longer have to calculate pixel position based on `width` and `height`: the `scale` takes care of this.
6. The `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables always contain the mouse's *device pixel* position: not scaled or translated. To resolve this, define two more functions:

   ```js
   function wMouseX() {
     return mouseX * (worldWidth / width)
   }

   function wMouseY() {
     return worldHeight - (mouseY * (worldHeight / height))
   }
   ```

   You can test this with the following code, to show the mouse coordinates (pixels) and their world coordinates (scaled and translated points):

   ```js
   wText(" x:\t" + round(mouseX), 0, 40);
   wText(" y:\t" + round(mouseY), 0, 20);

   wText("wX:\t" + wMouseX(), 200, 40);
   wText("wY:\t" + wMouseY(), 200, 20);

   fill("red");
   circle(wMouseX(), wMouseY(), 15);
   ```

Comment: Full example in [this snippet](https://gitlab.com/milohax/hax/-/snippets/2544821)